# How can I launch Chromium from Dash/Unity with switches?

Tags: unity-dash, chromium, .desktop

I want to launch Chromium browser with the `--no-referrers` switch, which was mentioned on [this site](https://www.darklaunch.com/2011/05/07/chrome-disable-referer-headers). However, I'm not sure how to do that.

Normally, I use the Dash to launch Chromium, how do I add the switch to block the referrers?

Thanks.

Comment: KnP B, glad it works.  Also for clarity reasons, If the answer was what you are looking for, (like you mentioned in the comment on the answer), would you be so kind to accept the answer (click the big 'V' on the left, below the up/down arrows)?

Answer (score 1):

You need to edit the `chromium-browser.desktop` file a bit, but best practice is to edit a local copy of it in `~/.local/share/applications`.

#### What you need to do

1. Copy the global `chromium-browser.desktop` from `/usr/share/applications` to `~/.local/share/applications`

   ```
   cp /usr/share/applications/chromium-browser.desktop ~/.local/share/applications
   ```
2. Open the file:

   ```
   gedit ~/.local/share/applications/chromium-browser.desktop
   ```

   Look for *the first* line, starting with

   ```
   Exec=
   ```

   Change it to:

   ```
   Exec=chromium-browser --no-referrers
   ```

   Save the file and log out/in to make Dash change its focus from the global `chromium-browser.desktop` file to the local one.

#### Alternatively

Maybe even better would be to set the option as a shortcut to your launcher. To do that:

1. Open the file (local copy, as described above) look for the line:

   ```
   Actions=NewWindow;Incognito;TempProfile;
   ```

   Change it into:

   ```
   Actions=NewWindow;Incognito;TempProfile;No referrers;
   ```
2. At the very end of the file, add a section:

   ```
   [Desktop Action No referrers]
   Name=No referrers
   Exec=chromium-browser --no-referrers
   OnlyShowIn=Unity;
   ```

   Then you'll have the option available as a shortcut, while you still can run `Chromium the "usual way".

   [image]

(As said, after log out/in)

Comment: thank you for your input, this is excellent information and exactly what I am looking for. Hopefully, this will serve someone else as well.

Answer (score 0):

Open the application "Terminal" like you'd open `chromium-browser` and type `chromium-browser --no-referrers` and hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>. Use chromium and after you closed it, wait a little and close the terminal.

Comment: Although this will work, this method would require me to use terminal each time then in order to use the --no-referrer switch.This is not a permanent solution, therefore I cannot accept it. But, thank you for your input.

Comment: Well, that's not clear from you question.

Answer (score -1):

Download [this.](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/precise/alacarte/) It is a program called Main Menu that lets you make launchers with custom commands. Create a new launcher and tell it to run the command `chromium-browser --no-referrers`. You can find a chromium logo on google and set it as the icon if you want. PS: To get the new launcher on the sidebar, search for it using the super (windows) key and drag it to the launcher.

Comment: It is a bad and unclean idea to have mutiple launchers, calling the same application in their main command.

Comment: Well, your method would work also. (I assume, I haven't tried it)

Comment: In principle, Unity is designed to show the application in only one icon. With multiple icons/launchers, calling the same application in their main command, windows will be grouped in only one of them, but not necessarily always the same, messing up the idea of the Unity Launcher.